# ScrollView rounded corners

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

I made a custom Image swiper withe ScrollView in React Native, but it looks bad when images with rounded corners move. Is there any way to round the corners of the ScrollView?
Those are my ScrollView styles:

```
style={{
     flexDirection: 'row', alignSelf: 'center',
     width: this.state.imageWidth,
     borderRadius: 20,
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` also inherits styles from `ViewStyles` so you can pass `borderRadius: 20` to it.

Comment: Does using horizontal scroll change anything?

Comment: Is there any parameter or something that could be the reason of this not working?